# JSF HandleRenderException due to NullPointerException

Tags: jakarta-ee, el, jsf-2.2

I've been attempting to render database information on a JSF page utilizing Java EL, however I've been getting back the following:

```
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error rendering View[/customerInformation.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And it goes on from there (see full error report below).

From my understanding, because none of the assertions I've incorporated in my code seem to be reached, the methods containing them are never actually executed. This leads me to believe that either:

1. According to a previous thread of mine, I may still be using EL incorrectly and experiencing issues because of some misunderstanding there. I may have moved beyond those bugs, but have I really understood the cause?
2. The bean, or something connected to it, is never initialized and thus causes the null pointer exception.
3. My use of the JSF tags does not actually accomplish what I am trying to do
4. Something else is happening I haven't thought of or understood yet.

Some system and library information:

- CentOS 6.5
- Eclipse Kepler IDE for Java EE Developers
- JRE System Library [java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45.x86_64]
- Apache Tomcat v7.0
- Apache TomEE 1.6.0 JAX-RS
- JSF Mojara 2.2 (javax.faces.jar)
- log4j 1.2.17 (log4j-1.2.17.jar)

The view: (customerInformation.xhtml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
        <title>Customer Information</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h1>Customer:</h1>
        <h:dataTable value="#{customerBean.getFirstCustomer()}" var="cust"
            id="custTable">
            <h:column id="idCol">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    ID:
                </f:facet>
                #{cust.id}
            </h:column>

            <h:column id="firstnameCol">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    First Name:
                </f:facet>
                #{cust.firstname}
            </h:column>

            <h:column id="lastnameCol">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Last Name:
                </f:facet>
                #{cust.lastname}
            </h:column>

            <h:column id="creditcardCol">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Credit Card:
                </f:facet>
                #{cust.creditcard}
            </h:column>

            <h:column id="cidCol">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    CID:
                </f:facet>
                #{cust.cid}
            </h:column>

            <h:column id="addressCol">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Address:
                </f:facet>
                #{cust.address}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The Backing Bean (CustomerBean.java):

```
package customer;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import customer.model.Customer;

@ManagedBean(name="customerBean", eager=true)
@SessionScoped
public class CustomerBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static transient Logger log =
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerBean.class.getName());

    private static final String DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe";
    private static final String DB_USER = "username";
    private static final String DB_PASS = "password";

    private Connection getConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.warn("Oracle JDBC Driver not found!", e);
        }

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.fatal("ERROR: Could not establish a connection to the database!", e);
        }

        assert(conn != null);

        return conn;
    }

    private ResultSet queryDatabase(String queryString) {
        ResultSet queryResponse = null;
        PreparedStatement query = null;

        if (queryString == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Connection databaseConnection = connect();

        try {
            query = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(queryString);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.warn("Failed to prepare database query!", e);
        }

        assert(query != null);

        try {
            queryResponse = query.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.warn("Failed to execute database query!", e);
        }

        assert(queryResponse != null);

        return queryResponse;
    }

    public Customer getFirstCustomer() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        ResultSet queryResponse = null;
        List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

        queryResponse = queryDatabase(
            "SELECT ID01, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, CREDITCARD, CID, ADDRESS FROM SCOTT.CUSTOMER_CC");

        try {
            Customer cust = new Customer();
            while (queryResponse.next()) {
                cust.setId(queryResponse.getInt("ID01"));
                cust.setFirstname(queryResponse.getString("FIRSTNAME"));
                cust.setLastname(queryResponse.getString("LASTNAME"));
                cust.setCreditcard(queryResponse.getString("CREDITCARD"));
                cust.setCid(queryResponse.getString("CID"));
                cust.setAddress(queryResponse.getString("ADDRESS"));

                customerList.add(cust);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.warn("Failed to build customer from query response.", e);
        }

        assert(!customerList.isEmpty());

        customer = customerList.get(0); // Arbitrarily pick the first customer

        return customer;
    }
}
```

Currently I've only created a method `public Customer getFirstCustomer()`. The goal is to change that over to a method `public List<Customer> getCustomerList()` in order to populate the data table with all customer's information. Will this be possible once I address my issues?

The Customer POJO (Customer.java):

```
package customer.model;

public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String creditcard;
    private String cid;
    private String address;

    // For brevity sake, the getters and setters are here (generated)
}
```

Now for the error log (I've set up a PhaseListener that added in information about the render phases of the application. You'll notice that the error occurs during the Render Response phase):

```
2014-02-24 15:55:50,666 TRACE [http-bio-8080-exec-3] - test.debugPack.DebugPhaseListener.beforePhase 23 - Entering phase: [RESTORE_VIEW 1]
2014-02-24 15:55:50,768 TRACE [http-bio-8080-exec-3] - test.debugPack.DebugPhaseListener.afterPhase 18 - Completed phase: [RESTORE_VIEW 1]
2014-02-24 15:55:50,773 TRACE [http-bio-8080-exec-3] - test.debugPack.DebugPhaseListener.beforePhase 23 - Entering phase: [RENDER_RESPONSE 6]
Feb 24, 2014 3:55:51 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/customerInformation.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:225)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:225)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1811)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:82)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:869)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1133)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Feb 24, 2014 3:55:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/JSF_Remote_Data_Test] threw exception [null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:225)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:225)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1811)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:82)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:869)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1133)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
2014-02-24 15:55:51,357 TRACE [http-bio-8080-exec-3] - test.debugPack.DebugPhaseListener.afterPhase 18 - Completed phase: [RENDER_RESPONSE 6]
```

I've already tested the JDBC code in a regular Java project, and was able to connect to and query the database, successfully displaying the output to the console. This at least demonstrated that the underlying interfacing mechanisms I am using should work, pointing my concern more to my use of JSF and EL.

Aside from wanting to better understand what is causing my issue, and how to go about fixing it, I would also appreciate some additional information. When, during the application lifecycle, is the instance of the backing bean created? Do I need, or is it better practice, to utilize an @PostConstruct method with my bean, and for what purposes (ie: create a member field for the Connection instance and acquire it in the post construct method)? Most importantly, what is EL doing, and is it possible to call a regular method (not a getter or a setter, as I am trying to do with `getFirstCustomer()` using EL?

Thank you very much for reading. I appreciate any help and advice!

Comment: Create new method which will return List and call this method in `h:dataTable`

Comment: Well yes. The method getFirstCustomer() I originally designed to just return the list. instead of taking the first element of the list and assigning it to the customer value, after the while loop it just returned the list. However, that also was giving me this selfsame error. So I need to resolve that before moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a very crude answer, and I will be looking more into the causes for my results.

However, in an attempt to isolate the issues in this project I set up a new workspace in Eclipse, copied the project folder over from the other workspace to the new workspace location on disk, then imported the project through Eclipse. After doing this I ran into some issues which were caused by not having the server connection set up for the new workspace. This was resolved by creating a new server instance within the workspace, keeping the defaults for Tomcat 7.0.

I then ran my project and received a class not found exception for com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener. This I knew to be set up in my web.xml file, so I quickly did an edit which removed the following lines

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

from my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

  <!-- Project Name -->
  <display-name>mkyong test</display-name>

  <!-- Context Parameters -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Landing Page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- Error Page -->
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>

  <!-- Servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Servlet Mappings -->
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Context Parameters -->
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Resource References -->

  <!-- Listeners -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

Again, I ran the project and this time the page rendered without tossing errors, and even displayed the information stored in my database.

The odd thing now is that the information represented by the table is two rows of repeated information. I have two customers stored in the database, but only one of them displays in both rows of the table. This is weird because I did modify the getFirstCustomer() method to return a list of customers instead of just the customer as seen above. So now it looks like this:

```
public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        ResultSet queryResponse = null;
        List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

        queryResponse = queryDatabase(
            "SELECT ID01, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, CREDITCARD, CID, ADDRESS FROM SCOTT.CUSTOMER_CC");

        try {
            Customer cust = new Customer();
            while (queryResponse.next()) {
                cust.setId(queryResponse.getInt("ID01"));
                cust.setFirstname(queryResponse.getString("FIRSTNAME"));
                cust.setLastname(queryResponse.getString("LASTNAME"));
                cust.setCreditcard(queryResponse.getString("CREDITCARD"));
                cust.setCid(queryResponse.getString("CID"));
                cust.setAddress(queryResponse.getString("ADDRESS"));

                customerList.add(cust);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.warn("Failed to build customer from query response.", e);
        }

        assert(!customerList.isEmpty());

        return customerList;
}
```

Regardless, this is a step close to getting the project functioning correctly, and does seem to solve the issue I originally asked about.

The strangest thing of all is that the solution worked for both projects in both workspaces, however the original project int he other workspace has run in to some other issues which make me believe that there are conflicts between some of my resource .jar files. I'll be looking more into it to see if I can pinpoint more so what exactly was going wrong and why this solution works.

Cheers!

Comment: The issue with the repeating rows is that in the method getFirstCustomer(), now better named as getCustomerList(), was that the customer object was initialized outside of the while loop. So within the while loop I was using the same object reference to add new data to the list, overwriting the old data. By moving the line `Customerr cust = new Customer()` within the while loop, this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it will be helpful for you, but it may help others.
I had the same issue caused by the commented EL:

```
        <!-- <ul class="topMenu">
            <li><p:link outcome="/pages/dashboard.xhtml" value="Dashboard"/></li>
            <li><p:commandLink action="tickets" value="Tickets"/></li>
            <li><p:commandLink action="#{navigationBean.navigateToProfile()}" value="Profile"/></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="font-size:10px;">(#{sessionScope['currentUser'].id})</a>
                <p:commandLink   action="#{userBean.logout()}" value="LogOut"/></li>
        </ul> -->
```

The correct way of commenting Expression Language is using `<ui:remove>` tag.